# Any later versions of python 3 that are compatible with python 3.2.5?

Tags: python, python-3.2

my school told me to use python 3.2.5 for compatibility reasons as that's the version that they use, but I've found that a few modules I would like, don't work with python 3.2

I was wondering if there's a way to have two versions of python installed or if any later versions are compatible with python 3.2.5?

Comment: Why, oh why? Tell them seriously to switch to Python 3.3 at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly have multiple versions of python installed. In my case I have coworkers that prefer Python 2.7 and so I have a virtual environment set up that will use python 2.7 instead of 3.4 (which i prefer). There are lots of useful cases when environments will save you headaches so do learn about them earlier than later.

Personally, I like to use the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution of python. With anaconda you can use `conda create --name env_name python=3.x package package1` this will create a python environment with python version 3.x named env_name and install packages: package and package1. If you want an empty environment simply omit packages. The documentation for this can be found [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-a-separate-environment).

However, as Antti Haapala points out 3.2 is not necessarily the most stable or compatible of versions. In fact conda has dropped 3.2 for environment creation, running `conda create --name env_name python=3.2` returns an error.

I'm sure your school has some reason they want to stick to 3.2, but in my opinion you might be best served by using 3.3 (or later) instead.

ps. referring to your previous question about pip; with anaconda there is a command `conda` which accomplishes the same thing. For example you can run `conda install pandas` to install pandas. If a package can't be found, searching the [anaconda  site](http://anaconda.org/) will give you info on how to add packages from other owners.

Comment: Hi, just wondering, does this work with windows 10? Your answer sounds like linux.

Comment: I work on windows 7, but there is no reason it shouldn't work on windows 10. It sounds like linux because these are command line operations. On windows 7 i type `cmd` into the search bar in the start menu to get to the command prompt.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get anaconda working with 2.7; do you know how to get mechanize working? `conda install mechanize` doesn't work and when I tried a few of the ones from here [anaconda search page](https://anaconda.org/search?q=platform%3Awin-64+mechanize) they don't work because some of the specifications were in conflict. Do you know if there's a way to install mechanize without these errors?

Comment: you can use pip to install mechanize with anaconda. pip and conda are both standard in the anaconda distribution. Try `pip install mechanize`

Comment: that worked, but it installed version 0.2.6 and I don't know if that version works with 2.7 because my Spyder IDE is using 2.7 and it says `ImportError: No module named mechanize`. I tried activating my python 3.5 environment but it didn't seem to change spyder, even after reopening the program. Do you know how to change spyder to use my current environment? or how to get pip to install a different version of mechanize?

Comment: That is odd. Did you have your python 2.7 environment activated when you ran `pip install mechanize`. I just tested this in my python 2.7 environment and it worked just fine.

Comment: Also you will need to have spyder installed on the environment as well. If not it will revert to running spyder from the default environment

Comment: I tried it again after activating my 2.7 environment, and it said `Requirement already satisfied`
My spyder says it's using Python 2.7 but I'm not sure if that means it's using my environment that I made.

Comment: is your default environment also 2.7? if not then you are running spider in your 2.7 environment. Have you tried opening the python shell and trying to import mechanize that way? You can run `conda list` to see a list of all packages installed in your current environment. If Spyder isn't on the list in the environment where you installed mechanize then that would explain your issue.

Comment: Thanks, spyder wasn't in the list for my 2.7 environment but I have installed it now, and it seems to be working. Thanks for your help!